# Automatically clicking multiple buttons on a page containing the same text and tag

Tags: javascript, click, greasemonkey, autofill, tampermonkey

I'm currently using a script that automatically clicks radio buttons associated with specified text (but lie within a specified tag; in this case, 'label').

When a page loads, any radio button with the text "Male" (given that it is within a label tag) is automatically selected. Here's the incomplete script I have been using to do this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Auto Clicker
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        *
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant        GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

const findAndClickParent = text => [...document.querySelectorAll('label > span')]
  .find(e => e.textContent === text)
  .parentElement
  .click();

waitForKeyElements (
  "label",
  () => {
    findAndClickParent('Male');
  }
);
```

Right now, whenever I visit a survey page, the first radio button that contains the text "Male" is selected. But if there are other buttons with "Male" as an answer choice, they remain unselected. I want to be able to select all of them - to click all buttons that would contain "Male," and not just the first. Any and all advice would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why only first radio button is getting selected in above code is .find is returning the first element which matches the text.

you can use `.forEach` to loop and click all the radio button having text Male

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('label > span')].forEach(e => e.textContent === "Male" ? e.parentElement.click(): null)
```

OR

You Can Use `checked` property for all radio buttons you want to be selected on page load.

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked="true">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works in the console. What would the full code look like using the waitForKeyElements method to wait before autofilling? Maybe by just replacing the [...doc] and after section?

Comment: Happy to help.
Yes you are correct just replace the section after [..doc] with the code suggested
Let me know if face any further issues.

Comment: Thanks again. One quick question: Is there any way I could rewrite the last paragraph of code (after the waitForKeyElements) to stream line it? Do I still need to include the findandclickparent in the second part?

Answer (score 1):

In the code below you could replace `.click()` with `.checked = "true"`. Or maybe have a method that sets checked to true and then call that method instead of `.click()`

```
const findAndClickParent = text => [...document.querySelectorAll('label > span')]
.find(e => e.textContent === text)
.parentElement
.click();
```